# Elasticsearch throwing http method exceptions. Symfony 4.4 on Platform.sh

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch, platform.sh

I'm using the FOS Elasticsearch bundle on Symfony 4.4 on Platform.sh and any attempt to populate results in error.

*Relevant config pieces:*

**composer.json**

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.3.0",
    ...
    "friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle": "^5.1",
```

**platform/services.yml**

```
searchelastic77:
    type: elasticsearch:7.7
    disk: 1024
```

**.platform.app.yml**

```
relationships:
    ...
    elasticsearch: "searchelastic77:elasticsearch"
```

**config/packages/fos_elastica.yml**

```
fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default: { url: '%env(ELASTICSEARCH_URL)%' }
    indexes:
        app_post:
            types:
                post:
                    properties:
                        title: ~
                        excerpt: ~
                        content: ~
                        author: ~
                    persistence:
                        driver: orm
                        model: App\Entity\Post
                        provider: ~
                        finder: ~
```

**.env**

```
###> friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle ###
ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://localhost:9200/
###< friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle ###
```

**In the platform.sh settings for this branch, I have the following variable configured:**

```
env:ELASTICSEARCH_URL = http://elasticsearch.internal:9200
```

**running `platform:relationships` on this branch yields:**

```
elasticsearch:
    -
        service: searchelastic77
        ip: ***
        cluster: ***
        host: elasticsearch.internal
        rel: elasticsearch
        scheme: http
        port: 9200
        url: 'http://elasticsearch.internal:9200'
```

---

The Error seems to have to do with incorrect HTTP methods.  Attempting to populate the index on the live server by running the command `bin/console fos:elastica:populate` yields the following exception:

```
Resetting app_post

In Http.php line 182:
                                                                                    
  Incorrect HTTP method for uri [/] and method [PUT], allowed: [GET, DELETE, HEAD]  
                                                                                    

fos:elastica:populate [--index [INDEX]] [--type [TYPE]] [--no-reset] [--no-delete] [--sleep SLEEP] [--ignore-errors] [--no-overwrite-format] [--first-page FIRST-PAGE] [--last-page LAST-PAGE] [--max-per-page MAX-PER-PAGE] [--pager-persister PAGER-PERSISTER] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command>
```

Attempting to update post entity on the production server also yields this error:

```
request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Elastica\Exception\ResponseException: "Incorrect HTTP method for uri [/] and method [POST], allowed: [GET, DELETE, HEAD]" at /app/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Transport/Http.php line 182 {"exception":"[object] (Elastica\\Exception\\ResponseException(code: 0): Incorrect HTTP method for uri [/] and method [POST], allowed: [GET, DELETE, HEAD] at /app/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Transport/Http.php:182)"} []
```

I have tried various combinations of Elastic search versions (5.2, 6.5 and now 7.7) and all are throwing the same errors.

Comment: I've the same problem. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: @Vincent I never did find a solution to this.  We ended up going with a third party service for search on this project.

Comment: Adding a trailing slash at the end of the of the url configuration seems to work on my side ;)

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered a similar issue when configuring FosElasticaBundle with Platform.sh, and I've found a solution.
I had the same problem as you, where the ELASTICSEARCH_URL on Platform.sh did not end with a "/".

In a typical Symfony setup, the following configuration works fine:

```
fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default:
            url: '%env(ELASTICSEARCH_URL)%'
```

However, on Platform.sh, the ELASTICSEARCH_URL does not end with a "/".

To resolve this issue on Platform.sh, you should use the following configuration instead:

```
fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default:
            host: '%env(ELASTICSEARCH_HOST)%'
            port: '%env(ELASTICSEARCH_PORT)%'
```

By specifying the host and port separately, you can accommodate the different format of the Elasticsearch URL on Platform.sh.

I hope this information is helpful and serves as a potential solution for anyone facing a similar issue.